# iOS Core data field name change in version

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my app.xcdatamodel I have a field name "labelColor" which has the key of colors for views. What i did is renamed the field name "labelColor" to "viewColorKey" in app1.xcdatamodel. Now when i open the app it doesn't take the keys of "labelColor" which in store because I use "viewColorKey" now. How do i merge this field in updated version. 
Eg:

labelColor = redColor

in new version there is no "labelColor" instead i changed to "viewColorKey"
I want it to show the previous version labelColor in new version. Which i should get viewColorKey = redColor

Am new to core data and so am unable to give a clear question. Please excuse my grammar mistakes.
Am using objective-c language